# Divide string to paragraphs

Tags: c#

I have this string inside text file

```
" *****.********* start *****.********* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa adddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddd end *****.********* start *****.********* frfrffrfrffr bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb gggggggggggggggg end *****.********* start *****.********* ppppppppppwpw hhhhheeehheee mmmmmmmmmmeem end "
```

And I want get each part between start word and end word to specific string variable Like

```
String first="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa adddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddd";
String second="frfrffrfrffr bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb gggggggggggggggg ";
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Look at `String.IndexOf` and `String.Split`. You need to show that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a List for the Strings found so that you do not have to count them. Then loop through the original string (we'll call it 's') and if start and end are found, get the text in-between these words. Repeat until finished, then use the values as you wish. Sample code with output in console provided below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        string s = " *****.********* start *****.********* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa adddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddd end *****.********* start *****.********* frfrffrfrffr bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb gggggggggggggggg end *****.********* start *****.********* ppppppppppwpw hhhhheeehheee mmmmmmmmmmeem end ";
        List<String> values = new List<String>();
        while (s.Contains("start") && s.Contains("end")){
            string g = s;
            values.Add(g.Substring((g.IndexOf("start") + "start".Length), (g.IndexOf("end") - g.IndexOf("start") - "start".Length)));
            s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("end")+ "end".Length);
        }
        foreach (string v in values){
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

*Note:* I noticed that in your question you ask for the text between `start` and `end`, but what you actually show as valid output is the text between `*****.********* start *****.*********` and `end`. If that is the case, replace `start` with `*****.********* start *****.*********` in the provided code and you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

Try this (Console App):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestRegex
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string input, string startTag, string endTag)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Escape(startTag) + "(.*?)" + Regex.Escape(endTag));
            MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(input);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
                yield return match.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = " *****.********* start *****.********* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa adddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddd end *****.********* start *****.********* frfrffrfrffr bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb gggggggggggggggg end *****.********* start *****.********* ppppppppppwpw hhhhheeehheee mmmmmmmmmmeem end ";
            var start = " *****.********* start *****.********* ";
            var end = " end";
            var temp = Parse(input, start, end);
            foreach(var s in temp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain your code, rather than just pasting it. This works but does not answer the question in a way that could be reused in a different but similar scenario!